# Show that the space G/H is regular

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I need to show that if $G$ is a regular Hausdorff topological group and $H \subset G$ is a closed subgroup, then G/H is also regular.

I was able to prove that the space G/H is Hausdorff, but I am stucked in showing that it is regular, i.e. that we can separate closed sets from points.

Any hints are appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Any $T_0$ topological group is $T_3$ (even $T_{3\frac12}$). This applies to the quotient $G{/}H$ as the subgroup $H$ is closed and so the quotient is even $T_1$. For any topological group, also $G{/}H$, Hausdorff and regular are equivalent.

Comment: That the quotient is a topological group is always true (if it’s normal in algebraic sense) and that the identity is closed needs $H$ is closed topologically. This implies $T_1$ etc.

Comment: If $H$ is normal right? but why is it in this case?

Comment: Otherwise $G{/}H$ is not even defined. So I suppose it must be given.